# how to add event in full calendar when onclick fullcalendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

**i am having problem adding event in fullcalendar, I am using option select to add event:**

- I am getting the Selected date and text on Alert , bit not able to post it on selected cell.
- but after pressing the submit button, no events are added.
  I have consulted several places but still can't do it, can you suggest me some ways, thanks a lot for helping me!

*currently i am using resourceTimelineDay v5*

[my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsteN.png)

**My code:**

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendarTimeline");
    var events = [];

    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        initialView: "resourceTimelineDay",
        headerToolbar: {
            left: "resourceTimelineDay",
            center: "",
            right: "",
        },
        height: "auto",
        locale: "ja",
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        select: function(info) {
            $('.modalCSV').find('input[name=time_start]').val(moment(info.startStr).format(
                'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
            $('.modalCSV').find('input[name=time_end]').val(moment(info.endStr).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
            $('.modalCSV').toggleClass('is-visible');

            $('#btn-sumbit').on('click', function() {
                calendar.addEvent({
                    title: '',
                    start: info.start,
                    end: info.end,
                    allDay: true,
                });
                calendar.refetchEvents();

                $('.modalCSV').toggleClass('is-visible');
            });
        },
        resourceAreaColumns: [{
                field: 'title',
                headerContent: 'スタッフ'
            },
            {
                field: 'count',
                headerContent: '出勤回数'
            }
        ],
        snapDuration: '00:15:00',
        resourceAreaWidth: "190px",
        views: {
            resourceTimelineDay: {
                buttonText: '日',
                slotDuration: "00:15:00",
                slotMinWidth: "10",
            },
        },

        resources: [{
                id: "1",
                title: "佐藤",
                count: "10",
                eventColor: "#b6d7a8"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                title: "山田",
                count: "12",
                eventColor: "#ffe5e5"
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                title: "田中",
                count: "3",
                eventColor: "#bbd6ee"
            },
            {
                id: "4",
                title: "鈴木",
                count: "5",
                eventColor: "#e7e6e6"
            },
        ],
    });
    calendar.render();
```

```html
<div id="calendarTimeline" class="w-full"></div>

    <div class="modalCSV">
        <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
        <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition border-3 rounded-md border__color--red200 w-auto xl:w-1/4">
            <div class="modal-header bg__color--red200">
                <h2 class="modal-heading text-center text-white font-bold py-2">再通知送信</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body p-3 sm:p-5">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    {{-- <form method="POST"> --}}
                    <div class="py-5 px-3 text-left flex flex-col gap-5">
                        <div>
                            <label for="time_start">開始時間</label>
                            <input type="text" name="time_start" id="time_start"
                                class="border__color--gray100 rounded w-full">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="time_end">終了時間</label>
                            <input type="text" name="time_end" id="time_end"
                                class="border__color--gray100 rounded w-full">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center mt-3 mx-3">
                        <button id="btn-cancel"
                            class="modal-toggleCSV w-32 sm:w-44 py-1 bg-white rounded border-2 border__color--gray300 text__color-gray100 hover:opacity-80">
                            キャンセル
                        </button>
                        <button id="btn-sumbit"
                            class="ml-3 w-32 sm:w-44 py-1 bg-white rounded border-2 text__color--red100 border__color--red200 hover:opacity-80 ">
                            送信
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You must give your new event a valid resourceId otherwise it will not be shown in the resource timeline view - because fullcalendar does not know where to put it.

Comment: can you give me an example? @ADyson

Comment: It's just adding one property to yohr event, nothing complicated! There are already examples in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events